# MySQL is giving me an error code 1072 what doesn;t sid exist I worked in Oracle LiveSQL it worked

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

MySQL is giving me an error code 1072 what doesn't sid exist I worked in Oracle LiveSQL it worked

```sql
create table student 
( sid numeric (4) primary key,
  first varchar(30) not null
);
```

Comment: That statement works for me without error in Mariadb.  Can you [edit] the question to show the _complete_ error output?

Comment: what is Mariadb...I have to use workbench

Comment: MariaDB is a MySQL fork.

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: I tried your code in MySQL and it worked fine too.

Comment: Error 1072 is related to foreign keys, but there's no foreign key in your code.